# Running synchronous method async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method that iterates a list of objects and for each item in the list fetches data from an external api.

Sometimes this can be very slow (naturally) and I'd like to add all my items to a Taks list instead to be able to run multiple threads at the same time. Is this possible without rewriting it all to be async? Today I'm using WebClient and fetches everything synchronously.

I tried something like this at first:

```
public Main() 
{
    List<Task<Model>> taskList = new List<Task<Model>>();
    foreach (var aThing in myThings)
    {
        taskList.Add(GetStuffAsync(aThing));
    }

    List<Model> list = Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray()).Result.ToList();
}

public async Task<Model> GetStuffAsync(object aThing)
{
    // Stuff that is all synchronous
    // ...
    return anObject;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any major problems with this, are you getting an issue, if so can you be specific about it?

Comment: Your code won't compile as it is. Show us actual code

Comment: This might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh696703.aspx

Comment: You *can* do this by simply wrapping everything with `Task.Run`. But it's a shame to waste those thread-pool threads to be blocked on IO, especially if your app is resource intensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using async here, you can just make `GetStuff` a normal synchronous method and use `Task.Run` to create new tasks (which will normally be run on multiple threads) so that your fetches occur in parallel. You could also consider using [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach() and the like, which is effectively similar to your current `Main` code.

Your async approach will *not* do what you want at the moment, because async methods run synchronously at least as far as the first `await` expression... in your case you don't have any `await` expressions, so by the time `GetStuffAsync` returns, it's already done all the actual work - you have no parallelism.

Of course, an alternative is to use your current code but *actually* do make `GetStuffAsync` asynchronous instead.

It's also worth bearing in mind that the HTTP stack in .NET has [per-host connection pool limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc(v=vs.110).aspx) - so if you're fetching multiple URLs from the same host, you may want to increase those as well, or you won't get much parallelism.

Answer (score -1):

Try this concept:

```
foreach(var aThing in myThings)
{
    Thread myTask = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(TaskMethod));
    myTask.Start(aThing);
}
```

and there must be a method called `TaskMethod` that is `void TaskMethod(object obj)`